# CORS proxy error in react app and express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, proxy

I am running a React app with an Express server back-end on **port:5000**. I am making a request to one of my endpoint using the state of the element to get some data and then render it to the page. I initially setup the proxy in the package.json file of the React app as `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` ([documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/). Now it was giving me a proxy **error saying cannot proxy to localhost:5000**. So I used **CORS** in my express server as a universal middleware for all of the routes using `app.use(cors())`.That removed the proxy error but the request is still not working (the code is not even reaching the endpoint because nothing is being logged to the console) and I am pretty sure it's because of the same error. Here are the code snippets

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
var elements = [];
  elements = await Element.find();
  res.json(elements);
});
```

```
    const getElements = async () => {
      try {
        console.log('getElements call')
        const data = await axios.get("/api/elements");
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({ type: GET_ELEMENTS, payload: data });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    };
```

```
  const { getElements, elements, loading } = elementContext;
    
useEffect(() => {
getElements();
}, [])
```

**Expected behaviour:** I want the endpoint to send **an array** name elements to the call which can then be set to the **elements state** using the reducer and then can be accessed by destructing in the end. I hope I have given adequate information. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is the `/` route handler definitely handling calls to `api/elements`?

Comment: Yes in the main server file I've setup express router as app.use("/api/elements", elementRouter);

Comment: Does it work if you enter the full URL in the axios request, i.e. `http://localhost:5000/api/elements`?